# Nervous About Hydronic Floor Heating

Tags: hydronic, floorheating

I recently installed electrical floor heating in a bathroom and I can set the temp to 90+ and it gets nice in there on the tile.

My plan in our new house is to put radiant hydronic floor heat throughout with mostly LVP on top and buying those panels where you can put the pex in grooves. LVP can only accept 85 degree tops. When I set our bathroom to 85 it's not that warm. How will this heat my entire house?

This project is a ton of money but I have doubts about it's actual heating ability. We will be putting in good insulation and redundant heating with a fireplace insert.

Can someone confirm they have used hydronic floor heat over LVP and it's kept their house warm in subzero temps outside? Where I am it get's into the teens fahrenheit often but every once in a while it's negative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know that there are different experiences in this area. Floor heating did not work for me. The thermal mass was too high. The house would get too hot by 10am, even though heating had been stopped at 8am. It is fine to maintain the ambient temperature as a backstop. Or it requires a modern predictive control system, not simple on off based on time and temperature. So beware.

Comment: Are you keeping your bathroom door closed when you test the floor at lower temps?  What is the air temp you are aiming for?  What is the temp in the surrounding rooms?

Comment: Have not used it, but it seems happy warm feet makes happy people.  Heat/warm air does rise, but it does depend if the system is matched to the house/outside expected temps.  Poor insulation/drafts will put most heating systems to shame.

Comment: "LVP planking should be kept between 65 and 85 degrees Fahrenheit, and flooring with an SPC core can withstand an even greater temperate range." It really should be ceramic though. The thermal loop is going to be operating at like 140f, but the floor itself is never going to get above 80f, unless you make the mistake of not having aux heat and it's -20 outside. *"will this heat my entire house?"* yes, except for the four last days of February. So, no. - There is no going back from this; imagine walking around your entire house going *ahhhh*.

Comment: How hermetically sealed is your house? Even if you have "R-21 walls, R-49 roof" *you still need aux heat*.

Comment: We are still in the building process but I'm confused as some say LVP and floor heat will be enough while others say it won't. We will be insulating the heck out of the house but are you saying you have experience LVP flooring with in floor heating that can heat the house just fine?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have LVP but I do have hydronic floor heating aka radiant heat. I have PEX tubing below a 3/4" plywood subfloor with 3/4" solid oak flooring on top, and no carpets. There's insulation below the PEX.

I live in New Hampshire and I have decent wall and roof insulation and windows and not much air leakage. My hydronic temperature controller adjusts the water temperature based on the outdoor temperature. Above 20F outdoors, I run 125F water. Below 0F I run 135F water. Between those temperatures, it's a smooth curve.

It has been as cold as -18F here two nights in a row, and the inside temperature remained steady.

If heat has been off and I raise the thermostat, nothing happens for the first two hours, then I gain one degree per hour. If I turn off the heat when it's cold outside, I lose half a degree per hour. So you can see I'm dealing with considerable thermal mass. Because of this characteristic, I set the thermostat at one temperature at the start of heating season and leave it there 24x7 until spring. The system is zoned and we keep different areas at different temperatures, but they are all set-and-forget till spring.

The floor surfaces run about 75-78F as measured with an infrared non-contact thermometer.

If you can run circulating water at 120-140F and still maintain your "85 degree tops", then in my opinion you can do hydronic floor heat with LVP.

Comments that claim that you must have a separate auxiliary source of heat when using hydronic floor heat are true only if the system is poorly designed, such as with inadequate flow, inadequate boiler capacity, inadequate tubing density or inadequate insulation. When properly designed, temperatures are rock steady and all living areas remain at the same temperature. You don't get chilly corners because you don't have a point source of heat. The entire floor, wall-to-wall, is the heat source.

So you get unexcelled comfort, but it comes potentially at the cost of operating expense because energy saving setback thermostats may not mesh well with your home / away / sleep schedule due to the extraordinarily long lag time between call for heat or heat cutoff vs room temperature.

Comment: House where I've seen this, boiler stays at 140 because it's also the HW. It runs the floor loop at full temp I think, just not for very long if not necessary. It's a hermetically sealed house and the furnace runs extremely seldomly. Radiant floor heat is the difference between a luxury house and not. *Nervous About Hydronic Floor Heating?* You'll feel silly for having asked this after you experience it. It's like living in a womb. "I have doubts about it's actual heating ability" *as the sole source of heat?* You should be, and it shouldn't be. Gonna have AC; might as well have a burner in it

Comment: Your insulation is exceptional if you don't have to adjust it throughout the season. You have no aux heat whatsoever?

Comment: @Mazura My boiler runs at 180F for DHW and for baseboard hydronic on the second floor. Radiant is 1st floor as described plus full finished basement with PEX in concrete floor. Water temp control for radiant is through an electric servo mixing valve. (Wax capsule mixing valves gave poor performance.) I have mini splits that I use for heat in the shoulder seasons, but once I turn on the radiant for the winter, the heat pumps are not used and no other heat source is needed. Insulation is R-21 walls, R-49 roof. House is not exceptionally tight.

Comment: @Mazura Not sure of your comment “don’t have to adjust it throughout the season.” You mean adjust the room thermostats, right? Why would I? With such a thermal mass, setback is pointless. A 4F setback would take 8 hours to achieve, then 5 hours to get back up to temp. So once I reach steady state in about 24 hours, it’s all self-regulating. If room temp drops a fraction of a degree, warm water circulates. Just add BTU. At water temp 125-130 most of the time, there’s no overshoot. Thermostats show room temp and set temp, and they are always the same.

Comment: Early Autumn I'm at like 72. Middle of winter I'm rocking +79, otherwise it's freezing in here with the zero insulation in my walls. "**I have mini splits that I use for heat in the shoulder seasons** [+1], but once I turn on the radiant for the winter, the heat pumps are not used and no other heat source is needed" - "R-21 walls, R-49 roof" is rather exceptional.

Comment: @Mazura R-20, R-49 is a building code requirement here (Zone 6 NH), so it's entirely commonplace since 2009. Stay warm!

Comment: @MTA - You said your floors stay at 75-78F so that range would work with LVP but I'm confused cause you said to choose either LVP or floor heating. We don't have concrete flooring, but a regular wood subfloor. Is there something that will work better than LVP that isn't tile?

Comment: @scri66le Sorry about that, I misinterpreted your statement about 85 degrees. I thought you meant that the circulating water must be kept at or below 85, which would never work. Please see my edited answer above which clarifies the point. I also have a regular plywood subfloor + solid wood flooring on 1st floor. LVP should work fine for you.